# How To Integrate ReactJS with OctoberCMS

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router, octobercms

I am trying to integrate ReactJS with OctoberCMS with react application residing inside a directory named react inside of the OctoberCMS installation. I am unable to set the routing properly. Hitting the URL directly for example `http://example.com/react/blog` results in a 404 page. If I navigate to the same url (using my navbar) after first visiting the homepage I am able to open the page successfully. Please help me setting the routes correctly.

Also how shall I couple the two(react and octoberCMS). I think that my approach of keeping the react build inside a folder in the OctoberCMS install is false. What should be the correct approach?

In package.json I placed `"homepage": "/react/"` it works fine but opening the page in a new tab results in a 404 page rendered by OctoberCMS

I also tried `<BrowserRouter basename = {'react'}>` With this I end up with a url looking like `http://example.com/react/react/about-us/`

I tried placing the build content directly inside the root directory of octoberCMS installation, resulting in a straight up 404 page on hitting my base url.

```html
<BrowserRouter>
  <TopBar />
  <Switch>
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} exact component={ HomePage} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/about-us`} exact component={ AboutUs} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/enquiry`} exact component={ Enquiry} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/contact`} exact component={ ContactUs} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/blog`} exact component={ Blog} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/terms`} exact component={ Terms} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/privacy-policy`} exact component={ PrivacyPolicy} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/request-purchase-offer`} exact component={ RequestPurchaseOffer} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sell-now/benefits`} exact component={ Benefits} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sell-now/how-dorrmat-works`} exact component={ HowDorrmatWorks} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sell-now/customer-reviews`} exact component={ CustomerReviews} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sell-now/offers`} exact component={ Offers} />
    <Route path={ `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sell-now/faqs`} exact component={ FAQS} />
    <Route component={ NoMatchFound} />
  </Switch>
  <Footer />
  <button onClick={ ()=> this.scrollToTop(500)} className = "scroll-top"></button>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I expect the react routing handling my routes instead of octoberCMS routing to a 404 page. Also When I try to open the page in a new tab it should not redirect to a 404 page.

Any kind of suggestion on how should I couple these two together would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your React application lives inside OctoberCMS is perfectly normal that all paths are handled by OctoberCMS's router. You can solve your issue in two ways:

- You can instantiate your app from a page handled by OctoberCMS, keeping in mind that you will have to define a route to redirect all requests to the entry point of your app. (you'll have to create a custom empty plugin and in its root create a routes.php file in order to define it)
- Alternatively, in the OctoberCMS .htaccess file you can whitelist the path to your entry point, in order to bypass OctoberCMS

Hope this helps, happy coding!